# Mongoexport get property of nested objects in CSV output

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I'm trying to get a CSV from mongo-db by using mongoexport.

My data is in this format:

```
{
    "_id": "99",
    "page_id": NumberLong(1122334455),
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "item_id": NumberLong(123456789),
            "item_name": "item1"

        },
        "1": {
            "item_id": NumberLong(987654321),
            "item_name": "item2"
        },
     },
    "last_updated_utc": ISODate("2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z")

}
```

To do this I'm using the following command:

```
mongoexport -f _id,page_id,last_updated_utc --query {page_id:1122334455} -d mydatabase -c mycollection --csv
```

This gives the output:

```
"99",1122334455,2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z
exported 1 record
```

The problem is that I need the `item_name` from the `data` elements in the output. These are a dynamic array which could contain no items or many items.

If I add `data` to the fields (-f) parameter, then it will just output this as a JSON string into the CSV, for each object, which doesn't help with using the data in future.

What I'm aiming to get is something like:

```
"99",1122334455,2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z,item1
"99",1122334455,2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z,item2
```

Almost denormalised, or like an outer-join in SQL. So that its just the `data` item IDs.

Is this possible? How can I get the `item_id` into the CSV output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoexport is a utility to allow exporting of your data to JSON by default or optionally CSV. Any subdocument information will be, as you have noticed output as JSON as it is the only valid representation of any data that is not a top level field. Thus it is designed for the basic use cases.

For anything else you will need to program your own solution, reading the data and transforming to CSV output.

If at all possible, can you rethink the structure of the data in the first place.The structure under `data` as keyed sub-documents doesn't make any sense. If it were an array, you could at least get half the job done using the Aggregation Framework.

```js
{
    "_id": "99",
    "page_id": NumberLong(1122334455),
    "data": [
    {
            "item_id": NumberLong(123456789),
            "item_name": "item1"

        },
        {
            "item_id": NumberLong(987654321),
            "item_name": "item2"
        },
     ],
    "last_updated_utc": ISODate("2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z")

}
```

This can be transformed with aggregation as:

```js
db.sample.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$data"},
    {$project: { 
       page_id: 1,
       item_name: "$data.item_name",
       last_updated_utc: 1
     }}
])
```

which yields

```js
[
     {
         "_id" : "99",
         "page_id" : NumberLong(1122334455),
         "last_updated_utc" : ISODate("2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z"),
         "item_name" : "item1"
     },
     {
         "_id" : "99",
         "page_id" : NumberLong(1122334455),
         "last_updated_utc" : ISODate("2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z"),
         "item_name" : "item2"
     }
 ],
```

Which is very much the denormalized form and gives us more hope of converting to CSV.

The problem with the structure here is since each sub-document in `data` is keyed and `data` itself is not an array, you are forced to programatically traverse each element. This also limits the utility of query functions that can be performed as each sub-document needs to be explicitly named.

So there is no tool, and your data is not making things easier. Change it if you can.

Comment: I didn't have control over the object structure unfortunately. Thanks for info.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: 1. structured fields, like arrays are actually ignored and do not appear in the output. 2. you can specify subfields simply by using mongoDb's field definitions   `field1.field2` for arrays you must include an index like `field1.0` etc.  See the mongoDb spec for your version.

Comment: Hi Neil, your aggregate example was very helpful. How would you take the denormalised data and produce a CSV output from that?

Answer (score 8):

**MongoExport**

To get the property of the nested object

Sample Document

```
{
"_id": "99",
"page_id": NumberLong(1122334455),
"data": {
    "0": {
        "item_id": NumberLong(123456789),
        "item_name": "item1"

    },
    "1": {
        "item_id": NumberLong(987654321),
        "item_name": "item2"
    },
 },
"last_updated_utc": ISODate("2013-12-19T13:17:43.994Z")
```

}
MongoExport syntax

```
mongoexport --host <hostname> --db <Database Name> --collection <collection Name> --csv --fields fieldname1,fieldname2 --out fileName.csv
```

Example : **Export in CSV Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db xyz --collection abc --csv --fields data.0.item_id,data.0.item_name,data.1.item_id,data.1.item_name --out important.csv
```

Example : **Export in JSON Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db xyz --collection abc --fields data.0.item_id,data.0.item_name,data.1.item_id,data.1.item_name --out important.csv
```

If you want to get the value which is of array then it is necessary to unwind the array.

**$unwind**:
Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

For more details Please refer this link

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It does what the asker wants and it works like a charm for me.